# how to check the property of object in angular?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am trying to update the property of object after calling $http request .And I also test that value using karma jasmine.But my test is fail why ?

Initial value of my object property is

```
**$scope.name='apple';**
```

after success I replaced the value like that

```
data.getData().then(function(data){
          console.log(data);
             $scope.name=data.data.name;

    })
```

I tested this but my test cases are failed why here is my code

http://plnkr.co/edit/ING6xCdNh8oqfurHWLAl?p=preview

```
  afterEach(function () {
    $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
    $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
  });
it('gets a name from data.json and check', function () {
    $httpBackend.whenGET('data.json').respond({ id: 123 });
    data.getData('data.json').then(function(response) {
      user = response;
    })
    $httpBackend.flush();
  expect($scope.name).toEqual('test');
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've edited your plunker
http://plnkr.co/edit/uwWG8wUmo7VNCDNfV4E9?p=preview

there was few things missing, first of all I moved the expected http call to beforeEach, otherwise all the tests would fail due to unexpected http request as the request happens EVERY time the controller is created

in the following test code you return for call `data.json` an object `{id: 123}`

```
$httpBackend.whenGET('data.json').respond({
    id: 123
});
```

but in controller you assign name of the response - `{id: 123}` to `$scope.name`

```
data.getData().then(function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    $scope.name = data.data.name;
})
```

then test clearly fails saying undefined is not equal to `test` so what you need in the test response is:

```
$httpBackend.whenGET('data.json').respond({
    id: 123,
    name: 'test'
});
```

you have to remember with that kind of operations about `$scope.$digest()` and `$httpBackend.flush()`